# Force voltage to 5V or 0V from solar panel

Tags: voltage, solar-energy

How can I ensure that a circuit powered with a solar panel will always receive 5V or 0V, but not something in between that would damage the circuit ?

I have a linear voltage regulator that ensures the voltage is not more than 5V, but it doesn't protect against undervoltage when the solar panel outputs a voltage lower than 5V + regulator dropout voltage.

Would a Zener diode with a 5V breakdown voltage after the regulator work ?
Are there solar panels that always output a voltage that is 0 or above some voltage (5V + regulator dropout voltage in that case) ?

Edit:

This is a hobby project. What I want to power is an Arduino MKR Wifi 1010. The arduino can already charge a LiPo battery when it is powered via USB. It will never draw more than 150mA.

The solar panel I have is described as 10W 12V, but it seems it can output less than 12V, hence the question about handling lower voltages.

Ideally, this circuit is always on. It will be "asleep" most of the time, only sending sensor data through wifi once an hour. Asleep meaning that it  uses the low-power mode of its cpu, disabling everything except RTC.

Comment: Naively this is typically the role of supply supervisor chips.  In more sophisticated settings, it may be desirable to use DC/DC conversion of a maximum power point tracker sort to achieve the best energy extraction from the cell, cache that in a battery or even ultracap, and then operate the system to the degree the need and energy budget permits.   Practically, your question is missing too many critical details - what is the purpose of this system, what is its rate of power consumption, and what are the advantages vs consequences of having it on or off?

Comment: I updated the question to include more details.

Comment: A linear regulator seems a very unwise choice here, you'll be wasting more than half of your available power.  You haven't justified the claim of damage though, and so have not ruled out the possibility of just using the brownout detector in the MCU.

Comment: I fried 2 boards already using this setup, and assumed the cause was undervoltage. No one answered why they broke when I asked at https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=715856.0 and https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/79898/fried-2-mkr-wifi-1010-after-plugging-them-to-a-solar-panel, but I didn't know at the time that the regulator output could be less than 5V so my description was partially wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> The solar panel I have is described as 10W 12V, but it seems it can output less than 12V, hence the question about handling lower voltages.

Yes, 10W at 12V is what it's going to produce under ideal conditions -- that means something approaching bright sunlight (if it's properly specified it'll tell you at what irradiance it delivers that amount of power).  Moreover, solar panels have an ideal voltage for any given panel, lighting, and temperature (and probably a bazzilion other factors); if you want to get the maximum power out of them you need an MPPT (maximum power point tracking) circuit.

You need a circuit that either only turns on your microprocessor when there's enough power available (hard, because you can only sense the voltage from the panel, and that's dependent on current), or you need some energy storage device.

If you don't mind your circuit coming on and off all the time, the simplest way to do this, what sounds like it's within your capabilities, would be to put a big capacitor, hard-wired in parallel with the solar panel.  Make it big enough that whatever you want to get done, you can get done as it discharges from -- say -- 10V down to 6V.

Build a simple analog circuit with a voltage reference (a zener will do, but there's better choices) and a comparator, that turns on the rest of your circuit (including your Arduino) when the capacitor voltage reaches some threshold (e.g. 11 or 12 volts -- even in dim light, you should reach this with no load on the panel, eventually.  Experiment around with this, though).  Build it with hysteresis so that it turns **on** at that high threshold, and turns **off** at whatever low voltage still gives you 5V to the Arduino (presumably 5.5V if you use a true low-dropout regulator; 6.5V to 7.5V if you use a 7805).

Provide a way to monitor the capacitor voltage -- you'll have a mild challenge in doing this so you don't inadvertently power the Arduino when it should be off; tapping off the power to the regulator should solve this problem.

On the Arduino side, have it do whatever you actually want while also monitoring the capacitor voltage.  Any time the capacitor voltage drops down enough that you only have enough energy left for one complete WiFi transaction, say "goodby" and go to sleep.  With a lot of attention paid to dotting 'i's and crossing 't's you could probably do this with the Arduino live all the time -- but that would require a lot of careful software and hardware work.

Here is **an example circuit** -- don't trust that it'll just work, hook it up and try it out.  Chances are you'll need to play with the resistor values, especially if you don't want to use the 1% values that I called out.  I can't guarantee that M1 will turn off all the way with the value of R6 that I call out -- that's for you to figure out.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCDqge.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I have spent a lot of time thinking about this basic problem. The problem with solar panels is that the open-circuit voltage is not very dependent on light level. Even when it is very cloudy out, they will develop pretty high open circuit voltage (almost the same as when it is bright and sunny). If you only look at open circuit voltage, you won't know whether there is enough light available to run your load.

In dim light, when you attempt to run your load, the solar panel voltage will crash. Then when you turn off or disconnect your load, the solar panel voltage will recover to nearly full voltage. Then when you connect your load, the voltage will drop out again, and this cycle will repeat until it is too dark, or until there is enough light to run the load without dropout.  There are three ideas I have come up with to combat this cycling.

### Proof Load

One is the "proof load" concept. Let's say your regulator needs at least 5.5V to allow for voltage drop. Let's say the maximum current is 100mA (use the real number for your circuit, 100mA is just arbitrary).

You could design a supervisor circuit that connects up a proof load to the panel, and keeps your regulator disabled or disconnected. The proof load would be a resistor sized to draw 100mA at 5.5V. (Let's say 51 Ohms).

When the supervisor circuit sees that the proof load voltage is over 5.5V, that means there is enough light available, so it disconnects the proof load and enables the regulator instead. The regulator will remain enabled unless and until the regulator input drops below 5.5V. Since the solar panel is loaded in both states, this should prevent rapid cycling in dim light.

### Ambient Light Detection

The second idea is to use a supervisor circuit and an ambient light detector. The ambient light detector must be placed very close to the solar panel. The supervisor circuit would monitor the ambient light level and enable the regulator when there is enough ambient light. This should work OK as long as the light on the sensor is the same as the light on the panel.

### Minimum Off Time

The third idea is to just slow down the switching by putting some kind of microcontroller in the loop. The microcontroller would enable the regulator, then, if the regulator input voltage crashes, it would turn off the regulator and wait for 10 seconds or so, and try again. This would prevent rapid cycling. But it still has the problem that it doesn't know if there is enough light available before enabling the regulator.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I really like Tim Wescott's idea of putting  a capacitor on the solar panel side and monitoring the solar panel voltage with the Arduino. That way you can transistion the Arduino to a low-power state when the solar panel voltage gets too low. And transition back to full power when it is high (like near open circuit voltage). Under low light, the arduino may cycle back and forth between low power and full power, but that should not damage any hardware, and the arduino 5V should remain at 5V from early morning until late evening, even if there are clouds or shading.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with an IoT project. I was using a 5 V regular USB power bank regulated "step-down converter" from a 12 V solar panel, but when the voltage of the solar panel reached 4.2 to 4.4 V the power bank froze, I do not know why. I did not want to use an active circuit to solve that problem or use a microcontroller.

So I came up with a simple passive solution by using a step-down DC-DC converter (12 to 5 V) in series with a step-up DC-DC converter (0.9 to 5 V).

Like this, your board will always have 5 V if the voltage is greater than 1 V. In your case 1 V will not damage the Arduino board.